Почему время отладки одного и того же кода с каждым запуском разная?
Использую библиотеку datetime для засекания времени отладки. Почему каждый раз, когда я запускаю код он показывает разное время. К примеру, один раз он показал 0:00:00.000028, в другой раз он показал 0:00:00.000022, а в третий раз он показал 0:00:00.000026. Вот код:
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()
print(1-1)
print(datetime.datetime.now()-start)

Конечно я понимаю, что пара микросекунд это маленькая разница, но интересно мне почему она существует?

Потому что у вас многозадачный компьютер и помимо вашего скрипта он занимается кучей других вещей.

... и во время исполнения этих задач он по разному нагрет и меняет степень тротлинга процессора. Горячий компьютер работает медленнее, холодный быстрее. Чтобы правильно померять, завершите на компьютере все остальные программы, выставьте фиксированную частоту процессора и получите стабильное время.

«пара миллисекунд» — всё же микросекунд

@andreymal спасибо, что подправили)

Это у вас ещё подозрительно свободный компьютер. Был бы загруженный +/- секунды уже были бы ))
